# Convert commands from prismatic joint to revolute for FollowJointTrajectory controller, robot arm gripper

Tags: ros, moveit, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robotic arm ([Cyton Gamma 300](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Cyton_Gamma_300_Arm)) with a 2-finger gripper, one joint mimics another (see the picture below).

My goal is to control and execute trajectories on the gripper using **MoveIt**.

[image: photo_of_the_gripper]

The gripper-related URDF/`xacro` chunk is as follows (the complete `xacro` description of the robot is [here](https://github.com/selyunin/cyton_gamma_300/blob/master/cyton_gamma_300_description/urdf/cyton_gamma_300.urdf.xacro)):

```
    <joint name="gripper_finger1_joint" type="prismatic">
        <parent link="wrist_roll" />
        <child link="gripper_finger1" />
        <origin xyz="${gripper_finger1_joint_init_xyz}" rpy="${gripper_finger1_joint_init_rpy}" />
        <limit lower="-0.008" upper="0.008" effort="100.0" velocity="1.0" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="gripper_finger1">
          <!-- Link Description omitted for brevity -->
    </link>

    <joint name="gripper_finger2_joint" type="prismatic">
        <!-- Joint Description omitted for brevity -->
        <mimic joint="gripper_finger1_joint" multiplier="-1"/> 
    </joint>
    <link name="gripper_finger2">
          <!-- Link Description omitted for brevity -->
    </link>
```

As it can be seen from the description, (i) the joints are defined as **prismatic**, and as it can be seen from the photo,
(ii) the gripper of the real robot is controlled by one 'dynamixel' motor, which is **revolute**. For the prismatic joint the displacement is specified in meters, whether for the dynamixel joint the rotation angle is defined in Radians.

My goal is to use *MoveIt*, both with Gazebo and the real robot and be able to pick/place objects with the arm,
leveraging available MoveIt capabilities. I am able to plan & execute trajectories for the manipulator (i.e. shoulder/wrist/elbow, 7 dynamixel motors in total), and bring the arm to the target position in space.

However, I cannot execute a trajectory for the gripper properly, since MoveIt reads URDF description and generates a trajectory w.r.t to limits in the URDF, (i.e. it provides displacements in meters, not angle in Radians).

To execute a trajectory in MoveIt I define `FollowJointTrajectory` controller as follows (complete configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/selyunin/cyton_gamma_300/)):

```
controller_manager_ns: controller_manager
controller_list:
  - name: cyton_gamma_300/arm_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - shoulder_roll_joint
      - shoulder_pitch_joint
      - elbow_roll_joint
      - elbow_pitch_joint
      - elbow_yaw_joint
      - wrist_pitch_joint
      - wrist_roll_joint
  - name: cyton_gamma_300/gripper_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - gripper_finger1_joint
```

For instance, If I want to plan the following trajectory (gripper should come from red to yellow):

[image: rviz_moveit]

I get the following on my `/cyton_gamma_300/gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/goal` (which is exactly a displacement):

```
goal: 
  trajectory: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: /world
    joint_names: ['gripper_finger1_joint']
    points: 
      - 
        positions: [0.00961187223614116]
        velocities: [0.0]
        accelerations: [-0.9530453139061077]
        effort: []
        time_from_start: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:         0
      - 
        positions: [0.008]
        velocities: [-0.042613731475556624]
        accelerations: [-0.9775129354039888]
        effort: []
        time_from_start: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:  58159883
      - 
        positions: [0.007838502345021854]
        velocities: [-0.058384310708380155]
        accelerations: [-0.6298771853005602]
        effort: []
        time_from_start: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:  60967905
      - 
      #and so on... the rest is omitted for brevity
```

Although the trajectory is fine for Gazebo, and will be executed as expected, for the real robot it is a problem since these command would be interpreted as rotation angle, which is not correct.

Question: how to map commands from FollowJointTrajectory to another type (i.e. from prismatic to revolute), and map the results back (i.e. feedback). Is there a standard way of approaching this problem?

*P.S. code is [here](https://github.com/selyunin/cyton_gamma_300/). Thanks in advance!*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259194/convert-commands-from-prismatic-joint-to-revolute-for-followjointtrajectory-controller,-robot-arm-gripper/) by [selyunin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30011/selyunin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirudh_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/29491/anirudh_s/) on 2017-08-09**:
Did you manage to figure it out? If yes,please update ,I am facing a similar issue where the robotic arm is placed on a linear actuator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I got it correctly, I wouldn't bother with that and declared a pseudo-prizmatic joint for the gripper. Then you can transform linear coordinates of this pseudo-motor to angular for the real robot, using something like

arccos(linear_coord / dynamixel_radius)

---

Originally posted by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) with karma: 115 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [selyunin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30011/selyunin/) on 2017-04-15**:
I am not sure what are you referring to with a 'pseudo-prismatic' joint. I cannot find this type of joint in the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint).
My question is about finding a standard way  of mapping one `FollowJointTrajectory` controller to another  and remapping back results